# Как случайно перемешать элементы двумерного массива?

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Существует двумерный массив, например, 6х6. Как его перемешать, используя Random?

Comment: Да, собственно, так же как и одномерный. Только переставляемые местами элементы будут иметь не один индекс, а два

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте алгоритм [тасования Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC), творчески применив его к двумерному массиву

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array